# Doze, different between Marshmallow and Nougat

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

Currently i reading in official google doc news about Android 7.0
I can not understand a few things.
They wrote Doze improve battery life by turn off network and CPU when user block the screen.
But how this works ?

1.I have Marshmallow in my device, and when my phone is blocked, i still get notifications from app with network (e.g. Messenger).

2.Second thing they wrote Nougat have improved this more by again CPU and network. So what is exacly differet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have Marshmallow in my device, and when my phone is blocked, i still get notifications from app with network (e.g. Messenger).

SMS does not usually go over the Internet, assuming that is what you mean by "Messenger" (many apps use that name). Plus, high-priority FCM push messages work despite Doze mode.

> Second thing they wrote Nougat have improved this more by again CPU and network. So what is exacly differet ?

There is a "Doze on the go mode" that kicks in even if the device is moving. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#doze_on_the_go) and in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perf).

Comment: I mean Messenger from Facebook, this app using network

Comment: u mean Firebase Cloud Messaging ?

Comment: last question, GCM push messages work despite Doze mode like FCM ?

Comment: @goodweather: High-priority GCM/FCM messages should be processed despite the device being in Doze mode.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notifications will still get through, but most services will stop running after a while if you leave your phone sitting on a table with the screen off.

For example Spotify still keeps running smoothly because it has a foreground notification. The battery savings come from when the OS can shut down most systems such as internet and geolocation as well as avoiding running other services for increasingly longer periods of time,for example reaching stretches of hours by the end of a typical user's sleep at night.

Now they're mainly doing what they were saying for a long time: background services have no guarantees of how long they will run. The biggest unintended consequence is that sometimes when they wake up there's no internet or geolocation is not available. And the time they run is less predictable.

There's still ways to wake up and perform tasks with perfect predictability using exact alarms or push notifications, depending on where the event is generated. But for most cases the recommended solution is using job schedulers.